# 404 Error when Testing Request class validation through Chrome Postman Extension

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

Below is my Controller Action method. You can see I passed a param of Request Class to validate before going to save the data in database

```
public function store(RoleRequest $request)
{
}
```

My Request class is below.

```
class RoleRequest extends Request
{
    private $Role;

    public function __construct(IRole $_role) {
        $this->Role = $_role;
    }        
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }    
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'Role' => 'required|max:20|min:4,
        ];
    }    
}
```

Above code works perfectly when I run it through web page(blade).

I created one more controller for API to Send save request. Below is the code

```
class RoleApiController extends Controller
{
    public function store(RoleRequest $request)
    {

    }
}
```

Issue comes, when I type just 1 char for role name and the Request class impose validation and I get 404 error This time I am sending request from Postman Extension in Chrome.

**Error Details**

[image]

Comment: how your routes looks like ??

Comment: I can show the Route. One thing I wanted to add that there is no issue if the validation id not imposed. Only issue is when validation is occurring while sending request from Postman Extension in Chrome. Also there is no issue when validation is occurring in case of sending request through web browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Validation `Request` class checks if your request is an ajax request or a normal request.

If it's a normal request it does: `redirect()->back()` with the validation messages in the session.

If it's an ajax request it shows a json object with the validation messages in it.

Frontend frameworks/libraries like for example jQuery add a header to an ajax request to let the backend know it's an ajax request. Laravel checks this header to decide what to do (using the `isAjax` or `wantsJson` methods).

Postman does not automatically send this header. So you should add one of the following headers manually:

```
Accept: application/json

X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Here is a screenshot of postman as an example:

[image]

Comment: I added the screenshot of Content type application json. Can you check that in my updated question?

Comment: May I ask the location in Framework for formatting the json message? I want to change that to show the message in more details.

Comment: I added a screenshot. You can edit the validation messages by adding a `public function messages()` in your `RoleRequest` file like: https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#customizing-the-error-messages

Comment: No, I am sorry. I meant, I am getting this as json result. `{"Role":["The role must be at least 4 characters."]}` and instead of this I wanted like this `{"Result":{"Data":null,"ErrorMessage":["The role must be at least 4 characters."],"Success":false}}`

Comment: That is quite hard to do, as you have to override the way laravel handles these "Validation Requests". It would be easier to move the validation part to the controller and format your own output and then returning it as json like: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#manually-creating-validators

Comment: I can't write anything in Controller's Action definition because Request class is passed as parameter in Action method. The validation code is in Request class.

Comment: That is why i am suggesting you could remove the request validation class and move the validation part to the controller for more control over the output for this usecase.